# Numerable union of open measurable sets

Tags: measurable-sets

So I've come across this question:

> given $A_{1},A_{2},...\ $ Jordan measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and given that $A=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_{n}}$ is bounded, is $A$ J-measurable?.

Now, I can think of $\cup_{q\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}}{\{q\}}$ as a counterexample for this, but I haven't been able neither to find a counterexample in which at least a numerable quantity of the $A_{i}$ are open (and not the empty set) nor to prove that if those $A_{i}$ are open then $A$ must me measurable, so if anyone knows how to answer in that case it'd be cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set). The important properties of $\mathcal{C}$ are the following: $\mathcal{C}$ has Lebesgue measure $1/2$, is a perfect subset of $[0,1]$, and has empty interior. In particular, $\mathcal{C}$ is not Jordan measurable, as having empty interior implies its inner Jordan measure is $0$, while having Lebesgue measure $1/2$ and being closed & bounded implies its outer Jordan measure is $1/2$.

Let $U = (0,1) \setminus \mathcal{C}$, which is a bounded open set. $U$ cannot be Jordan measurable, being the set difference of the Jordan measurable set $(0,1)$ and the Jordan nonmeasurable set $\mathcal{C}$.

But $U$ *is* still open, so it is a countable union of bounded open intervals, and those open intervals are clearly Jordan measurable. Thus, we have a union of countably many open sets which is bounded but not Jordan measurable.